# Как избежать копирование кода?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь разобраться как избежать копирования кода.

Вот абстрактный класс `Kontroller` мог бы иметь `List` `spisokKontoliruemih`

С которым работали бы наследники.

И вот что то не соображу...

`KontrollerGruzchikov` должен работать с `List` из объектов `Gruzchik`

`KontrollerKomplectovshikov` должен работать с `List` из объектов `Komplectovshik`

И в итоге, получается, что приходится копировать однотипные методы, потому что у одного `List` из одних объектов, у другого из других.

Если кто то меня смог правильно понять, как такое положение вещей исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контроллер грузчиков:

```
internal sealed class KontrollerGruzchikov : Kontroller
{
    private List<Gruzchik> spisokGruzchikov;

    // Куча ещё всего

    private void Kontrol()
    {
        foreach (Gruzchik gruzchik in spisokGruzchikov)
        {
            // Какой то код
        }
    }
}
```

Контроллер комплектовщиков:

```
internal sealed class KontrollerKomplectovshikov : Kontroller
{
    private List<Komplectovshik> spisokKomplektovshikov;

    // Куча ещё всего

    private void Kontrol()
    {
        foreach (Komplectovshik komplectovshik in spisokKomplektovshikov)
        {
            // Какой то код
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `у одного List из одних объектов, у другого из других.` - ну так делайте обобщение класса/метода, что вам там нужно. `class SomeClass<T>{ public List<T> Items; }` `var someClass = new SomeClass<int>(); int first = someClass.Items[0];`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ про <T> ещё ничего не изучал, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [обобщение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes).

Я опечатки в коде поправлю, если вы не против

```cs
internal sealed class GenericController<T> : Controller
{
    private List<T> items;

    private void Control()
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать можно будет с любым типом

```cs
var controllerGruzchikov = new GenericController<Gruzchik>();
var controllerKomplectovshikov = new GenericController<Komplectovshik>();
```

Comment: есть ещё некоторые проблемы, не могу в универсальном абстрактном классе обращаться к свойству `Status`, вот так в `foreach` `item.Status` унаследованное от `Rabotnik` и приходится снова копировать код в производных

Comment: Создать отдельный вопрос ?

Comment: @Алексей добавьте [ограничение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) `GenericController<T> : Controller where T : Rabotnik`

Comment: я попробовал сделать вроде как логичнее в моем случаем `Kontroller<T> where T : Rabotnik, new()` - но теряю связь с `Rabotnik` - т.е. не могу использовать методы класса `Rabotnik` в классе `KontrollerGruzchikov`

Comment: Вроде разобрался `Kontroller<T> : Rabotnik where T : Rabotnik, new()`

Comment: @Алексей `new(), Rabotnik` - обратный порядок

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0401?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0401)

Comment: @Алексей а, точно. Но я его и не использую, так как в обобщенных типах очень редко требуется вызывать конструктор обобщенного типа.